# How to return text to normal color after using the perl module ANSIColor?

Tags: perl, ansi-escape, ansi-colors

I recently found the very fun perl module Term::ANSIColor for changing my text color. Basically, all i need to do to change perl stdout text color is something like...

```
print color("red")."My sample text\n";
```

However, after exiting the script, my terminal is now only printing in red as well! Is there some function for return the console to the original color that I can include at the end of my script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try,

```
print color 'reset';
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `colored()` instead of `color()`. This will reset the coloring after the string is printed:

```
print colored("My sample text\n", "red");
```

Answer (score 4):

[Term::ANSIColor](http://perldoc.perl.org/Term/ANSIColor.html) doc page says that to get back to normal text you should use `reset` keyword.

```
print color 'bold blue';
print "This text is bold blue.\n";
print color 'reset';
print "This text is normal.\n";
```

Also I recommend to look at `Constant Interface`